# Android SQLiteDatabase insert method only work once

Tags: android, sqlite, insertion

I really don't know what is happening to my code. At first, i was able to insert record to my table, then in my second try it just don't run. Please Help. I passed the username through intent which pretty works.

**First**

```
    String pass = txtpass.getText().toString();
    String repass = txtpass2.getText().toString();
    String secA = txtans.getText().toString();
    String secQ = txtQ.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Message.message(this, pass+"and"+repass);


    if(pass.equals(repass))
    {

        long id = mh.insertNewAccount(username, pass, secQ, secA);

        if(id < 0)
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccesful");
        else
        {
            Message.message(this, "You may now logged in! Enjoy your experience!");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);

            Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
            bnd.putString("username", username);            
            intent.putExtras(bnd);

            txtpass.setText("");
            txtpass2.setText("");
            txtans.setText("");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Message.message_short(this, "Password didn't match!");
        txtpass.setText("");
        txtpass2.setText("");
    }


}
```

**Second** - insertNewAccount() Function

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_ID, "");
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_USERNAME, name);
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_PASSWORD, pass);
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_SECANS, secA);
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_SECQUE, secQ);

        long id = db.insert(MyHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return id;
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table (and why do you pass "" for USER_ID)?

Comment: in `SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();` what is `helper`? Try `this` instead.

Comment: Would that derive from SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Comment: Rob's right.. sounds like a schema issue.. like setting USER_ID as a PRIMARY KEY :)

Comment: USER_ID is actually an autoincrement primary key. I already try to remove it and i just bring it back again.

Comment: **the first one i tried-it is successfully inserted**'public long insertInitialRecord()
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_USERNAME, "taylor13");
   contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_PASSWORD, "pass");
   contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_SECQUE, "What is your mother's maiden name?");
   contentValues.put(MyHelper.USER_SECANS, "Dela Cruz");
   long id = db.insert(MyHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
   db.close();
   return id;
  }'

Comment: Is it working for you by removing the put on USER_ID?

Comment: i already tried it. nothing happened.

Comment: already solved it. You just need to call constructor always when starting another activity.:)

Comment: What is the reason for the [run] tag?